# Installing OpenCV 3.2.0 on RaspberryPi 3

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I'm having trouble installing OpenCv on my Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian. Does anyone have a guide or script that I can run to make this easy? I don't want to use a virtual environment.

I have tried using pip but it installs opencv 2.4.9 which is not compatible with the cv programs I want to use. I have also tried running various scripts but they all seem to have issues during compiling. 
`sudo apt-get install python-opencv`
also does not work and installs an older version that I can not use.

I am new to linux and rpi so any advice would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Try following instruction listed here , https://github.com/TechBubbleTechnologies/IoT-JumpWay-RPI-Examples/blob/master/_DOCS/2-Installing-OpenCV-3-2-0.md

Comment: Thank you so much. This actually worked. Most helpful thing I've seen in the last couple days of working on this.